# Duda con script en bash. Sumatorio de n números introducidos por teclado (no por argumento)

Tags: linux, bash, script

Tengo que hacer un script que me esté pidiendo por teclado números y me los vaya sumando y mostrando la cantidad acumulada.
Y el programa acabar cuando introduzca un número negativo.

He hecho el script siguiente que funciona pero...

Pero no me convence con el uso del seq en el for para usar eso como acumulador, no se me ha ocurrido hacerlo de otra forma.

¿Formas de hacerlo más... ¿Elegantes??

Edito: Elegante no es la palabra, sino que si lo que estoy haciendo es correcto en bash o hay una forma de hacerlo "normativa" o menos "rebuscada".

Gracias!

```
#!/bin/bash
#numeros2
#suma acumulada de números


i=0
suma=0
while [[ true ]]; do

echo "Introduzca un número: "
read num

if (($num < 0)); then
echo "Número negativo, saliendo del programa."
break
fi

for i in $(seq $num $num); do
suma=$(($i + $suma))
done
echo "La suma de los anteriores números es $suma"


done
```

Comment: "Elegante" es buena palabra

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

#numeros2
#suma acumulada de números

declare -i suma=0
declare -i i=0
declare num=
while : ; do

    echo "Introduzca un número: "
    read -r num

    # ¿Es un número?
    if [[ "${num}" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        # ¡Sí! 
        if [[ $num -lt 0 ]]; then
            echo "Número negativo, saliendo del programa."
            break
        fi
        # Restableciendo la suma a cero 
        suma=0
        # Haga un bucle sobre el número más bajo (estrictamente) que el número dado. 
        for (( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )); do
            # Posible porque "suma" se declara con "declare -i" 
            suma+=i
        done
        echo "La suma de los anteriores números es $suma"
    else
        # ¡No!
        echo "'${num}' no es un numero"
    fi

done
```

Comment: `while [[ true ]]` se podría reducir a `while : ;`, dado que `:` no sólo regresa siempre 0, sino que no es evaluado. Aunque puede no ser tan claro.

Comment: Ups. Acabo de ver que el mismo OP fue el que puso ese `while [[ true ]]`

Comment: Había tomado el código de Zer0. Yo solo simplifiqué

Comment: Creo que el OP requiere de otra funcionalidad a la que planteas. Si mal no entiendo la pregunta quiere que se vayan ingresando números y éstos se vayan sumando y el resultado esté por pantalla, ¿no? De este modo, si ingresamos un 5, veremos un 5, si luego ingresamos un 4, veremos un 9, si ingresamos un 1, veremos un 10... Para ello habría que eliminar la sentencia `suma=0` y el bucle `for` y sustituirlo por la sentencia `suma+=num`. El resto de la lógica implementada esta perfecta.